# Delay for every command execution in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm a newbie here so please forgive my ignorance. I just want to ask if there is a way to put a delay for each commands execution in a shell script.

This is my current setup

```
command1
sleep 1
command2
sleep 1
.....
.....
command1000
sleep 1
```

Is there a way to put just 1 sleep command ( delay 1 second) after execution of each command. Thank you in advance!

Br,
Mark

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: sorry i didnt specity. I'm using a bash shell.

Comment: `command1; sleep 1; command2; sleep 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash (but not other shells) you can do this with a debug trap:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'sleep 1' DEBUG
for word in The GNU General Public License is a free, copyleft license
do
  printf '%s ' "$word"
done
```

Here's `help trap`:

> ```
> trap: trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
> ```
>
> Trap signals and other events.
>
> If a SIGNAL_SPEC is DEBUG, ARG is executed before every simple command.

Comment: Thanks a lot!it works! i put trap 'sleep 1' DEBUG at the beginning of my script!I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi that_other_guy, i just have an extra question if you are not busy,  in my script i put set -e in order to close the script if there is an error. I have a command that was executed fine but script still close. Although the command was executed without output (meaning no existing configuration in the equipment), I thought "set -e" will close the script only if the command is wrong or there is a syntax error.Any idea on this, or maybe my understanding is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `set -e` may (but is not guaranteed to) exit the script when the command itself reports failure. Some commands report failure even though they completed their job perfectly in order to signal a testable condition, like how `grep` "fails" if it can't find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
declare -a cmd_list=("echo how" "echo are" "echo you")

for cmd in "${cmd_list[@]}"
do
  eval "$cmd"
  sleep 1
done
```

You have to replace the `echo <param>` with your commands and args.

Explanation:
I am have declared an array of commands in strings(first line), then I loop through the array and evaluate(`eval "$cmd"`) each string. After the command from the array, a `sleep` command is executed.

Comment: Hi shiva! Thanks a lot for your help! Its very nice to include explanation! I havent tried your scipt but I'm sure it will work. I'm a newbie with scripting. I will  study your script and will try in few hours. Thanks in advance again! I will let you know of the result.